# what's different between Object.prototype.toString.call and typeof

Tags: javascript

I'm noob of javascript and I'm confused what's difference with following methods.

```
function foo(){};
var bar = new Object();

Object.prototype.toString.call(foo).slice(8, -1);    // output "Function"
typeof foo;                                          // output "function"

Object.prototype.toString.call(bar).slice(8, -1);    // output "Object"
typeof bar;                                          // output "object"
```

Comment: They do totally different things: [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override what gets returned from `typeof`

```js
var MyObject = function() { };
MyObject.prototype.toString = function() { return undefined; }
var x = new MyObject();

console.log(typeof x);
console.log(x.toString());
```

If you're interested in JavaScript`s methods, check out MDN:

[MDN typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

[MDN toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: You can indeed change what `x.toString()` returns by changing `x`'s prototype, but you **cannot** change the return value of `Object.prototype.toString.call(x)`. Your example showcases the former, while OP is asking about the latter. More relevant to the question: there are many cases where `typeof` and `Object.prototype.toString` have different results (some are in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31460296/1321716)).

Answer (score 4):

The most common application for the `toString` 'hack' is to figure out what type of object you're dealing with:

```
typeof(new Array())  === "object";
typeof(new Date())   === "object";
typeof(new RegExp()) === "object";

Object.prototype.toString.call(new Array()).slice(8, -1)  === "Array";
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date()).slice(8, -1)   === "Date";
Object.prototype.toString.call(new RegExp()).slice(8, -1) === "RegExp";
```

For example, jQuery 1.11 uses this to [check whether a given object is an array](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/8c1d84292df31d27de3a843508efeff926bc290b/src/core.js#L206). jQuery 2 and higher [uses the native `Array.isArray`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/64f7d10980a5e9f2862f1239a37d95e6c39e37ec/src/core.js#L206) supported by modern browsers.

Besides, there are many cases where the two return different results, most commonly when using the object wrappers around primitive types:

```
typeof(new Number(5)) === "object";
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Number(5)).slice(8, -1) === "Number";

typeof(new String("hi")) === "object";
Object.prototype.toString.call(new String("hi")).slice(8, -1) === "String";
```

Comment: For `typeof` any object instantiated with `new ...` returns "object", so if that is your use case then typeof does indeed not help. However most of the time strings and numbers are not instantiated like that, MDN explicitly states that it is dangerous and should be avoided... anyway I mostly wanted to note that `typeof` always returns lowercase strings, so if you have an object `foo` with a string property `foo.bar`, then `typeof(foo.bar) === "string";`
([MDN | typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof))

Answer (score 0):

**toString()** is a method, that returns **a string that represents the current object** (ex: Function). you can override it to return anything you want.

**typeof** is an operator. You use it to **get the type of object** (as a string). And you can not change (overloading) it like some other languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
const str1 = "normal String"
const str2 = new String("using String constructor")

typeof str1 // 'string'
Object.protoType.toString.call(str1) // '[object String]'

typeof str2 // 'object'
Object.protoType.toString.call(str2) // '[object String]'
```

Object.protoType.toString.call(str2) can used to find string which are create using String constructor as our typeof doesn't work for the same