# How to test whether `fn` is a function(callable)?

Tags: javascript

In which condition will `Object.prototype.toString.call(fn) === '[object Function]'` and `typeof fn === 'function'` return different results?

I saw the function `isCallable` on mdn (see [line 4 - line 7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill)):

```
var isCallable = function (fn) {
    var toStr = Object.prototype.toString
    return typeof fn === 'function' || toStr.call(fn) === '[object Function]'
}
```

I'm wondering the difference between these two tests, is one of them superfluous?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's different between Object.prototype.toString.call and typeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459821/whats-different-between-object-prototype-tostring-call-and-typeof)

Comment: "These two functions" I only see one function. Also to improve readability, please don't put half the question in the title.

Comment: @DanFromGermany The two are `typeof fn === 'function'` and  `toStr.call(fn) === '[object Function]'`, also, edited the title, thanks

Comment: I have no idea what this code is supposed to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.prototype.toString` returns the value of the object's internal [[Class]] property, it isn't really a Type.
The value of this internal property represents the specification defined classification of an object (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250379/what-is-the-call-function-doing-in-this-javascript-statement/3250415#3250415)).
The value of the [[Class]] internal property for host objects -as DOM elements- can be anything, it is completely implementation-dependent.

So, the best way to test whether `fn` is a function is to use `typeof fn`.
Not only is it faster but the ECMAScript specification ensures that all functions have a type of "function" and that only functions can have a type of "function" (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17108198/709439).

Comment: So is it enough to just use `typeof fn === 'function'`?

Comment: Yes, that is the best solution.

Comment: **Note** ... @djy ... not every function is _callable_ though, some can only _construct_, quite a lot need to be invoked with the `new` operator.